# MVC 4 Why does not show the promp message?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I am trying to study html5 by the book [Pro-HTML5-Visual-Studio-2012](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430246383), but now I am in the topic `HTML5` and `MVC4`.

The example that I'm traying to do is easy, only I need to create a Basic model, view  and add the Editorfor Like:

```
namespace Chapter3.Models
{
    public class FeedbackModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Email", Prompt ="Enter your Email"), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the view

```
@model Chapter3.Models.FeedbackModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Home"))
        {
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Feedback page</legend>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
                </div>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the editor

```
@{
   @Html.TextBox("",null, new { @class = "text-box single-line", type="Email", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark})   

}
```

But My problem is that I can´t see the Prompt message or Placeholder, I know that it's a noob question but It's my first time trying MVC.

I hope anyone can help me

Comment: what browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome `Versión 27.0.1453.94 m ` And Mozilla Firefox `Version 15.0.1.` All work even this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found my problem few days Ago. The problem was in the directory that I was creating the  editor, It was in `/Views/share/EditorTempletes` And the route is `/Views/share/EditorTemplates`

I tried it and Works.